# bash: how to return string with newline from function?

Tags: bash, sh

I need to save the following in a file using function.

```
[hello]
world
```

I try a couple of ways but none works.

```
#!/bin/bash


create_string() {
  str="[${1}]\n"
  str="${str}world\n"
  echo $str
}

create_string hello >> string.txt
```

The file is like this.

```
[hello]\nworld\n
```

Comment: Try `echo -e $str`

Comment: To get all the possible spaces in `$1` correct in the string you build up, quote it: `echo -e "$str"`

Comment: If you use `printf` for output you don't have to worry about options to preserve formatting characters and `printf` is far more CAPABLE than `echo`. e.g. `printf "[%s]\nworld\n" "$1"`

Comment: Always quote your variables.

Comment: And use `printf` to print formatted strings, not `echo`.

Comment: `echo -e` is unpredictable; depending on which shell you're using, and maybe what shell options and/or environment variables are set, and even what options the shell was built with(!), it may do something unexpected like print "-e" as part of the output. My recommendation: never use `echo` with *any* options, or when there are any backslashes in the string to be printed. Use `printf` for all complex cases to avoid weird behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `printf` to print formatted strings.

```
create_string() {
    printf '[%s]\nworld\n' "$1"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to multiline output, I like to use `cat` with a here document with `EOF` as the delimiting identifier, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

create_string() {
    cat <<EOF
[$1]
world
EOF
}

create_string hello >> string.txt
```

Which creates `string.txt` with the newline markers required:

```sh
$ od -c string.txt
0000000    [   h   e   l   l   o   ]  \n   w   o   r   l   d  \n        
0000016
```

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells
- https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents

Comment: `cat` isn't necessary. `echo "..."`, with the same newlines in quotes as in the here document, would suffice.